# How to run JAR in an IntelliJ plugin

Tags: java, intellij-idea, intellij-plugin

To run a JAR in IntelliJ one can simply right-click on the JAR in module and select **Run 'xyz.jar'** or **Debug 'xyz.jar'***

How can I run/debug a JAR in an IntelliJ plugin (e.g. as an menu entry in the *Tools* menu) so that it behaves and looks like the one above (including the run tool window)?

I already have defined the action handler (as sub-class of `com.intellij.openapi.actionSystem.AnAction`) in the plugin.xml. The location of the JAR as also already known.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The perhaps easiest way is to use Run Configurations as described here: https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/IDEADEV/Run+Configurations